# Scheme: "Contract Violation" when trying to compare elements of two lists

Tags: scheme, racket, cdr

I am trying to compare elements in two different lists in scheme, using DrRacket. If m1 is less than m2, I need to return true. Otherwise, return false. I am getting the following error:

> <: contract violation   expected: real?   given: (3)   argument
>   position: 1st   other arguments...:

Would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks!

```
#lang scheme

(define t '( "Apple" 3))
(define t2 '("Orange", 1))


(define compare (lambda (m1 m2)
                (if (<(cdr m1)(cdr m2)) #t #f)
                  ))

(compare t t2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cdr` of a list like `("Apple" 3)` is not `3` but, as the error message tells you, a **list** with a single element: `(3)`. You cannot compare lists with the function `<`, which is thus signalling the contract violation.

Graphically:

```
m1 --> [A|Y]
        | |-----> [A|Y]
     car|  cdr     | |-------> NIL
        V       car|   cdr
      "Apple"      V
                   3
```

Thus:

```
(car m1) ;; "Apple"
(cdr m1) ;; (3)
(car (cdr m1)) ;; 3
```

`(car (cdr m1))` could also be shortened to `(cadr m1)`. Though note that it's probably better to use `first` instead of `car` and `rest` instead of `cdr` (if the selected language allows you to).

Also, don't write

```
(if (some-test) #t #f)
```

when `some-test` already returns either true or false, just write

```
(some-test)
```

Comment: That made a lot of sense, and solved my problem completely. Thanks!